# Report Criteria for Parent Child

Tags: reporting, joined-reports, childrecords

I have a parent child objects (just lookup relationship).

Can I get a report with All Parents who do not have **at least 1 Child in Active** Status?  This is to identify any Parents who do have an Active child.  I don't want to use triggers anything here to update.  I'm okay even for a complex report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working with Cross Filters with the right kind of Report Type.  Choosing the right type of Report type was the key here.

I chose `Accounts with Contacts` report type (implies it will show only the Accounts with at least 1 contact) and then I added **cross filter** `WITHOUT Contacts` with `status = 'Active'`  This report gave Accounts with contacts who do not have atleast 1 active contact.

Answer (score 2):

May be you can use Cross Filter option from Salesforce Reports

[How To Use Cross Filters in Salesforce Reports](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3jylFrXhow)

Use cross filters to filter a report by an object's child objects using both WITH and WITHOUT conditions. For example, filter a report to show accounts that have cases but don’t have activities.

Below are the reference link for Salesforce Document,
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_cross_filters_both.htm&language=en

Comment: I tried cross filters too.  I cannot use "WITHOUT" because I need child.  So, I used WITH.  But how do I check "if at least one is Active child"

Comment: Probably you might not get a option to find if there at least one Active child record. But, you can add a filter on Child record to get all child records with status as Active.

Comment: That's the problem!